Picking instances from realized instances
I have some instances that have been realized and modified after realization. Using these as a collection I want to do an instance on points with pick instance. I have tried various things but none seem to work.

Use "Split to Instances" to create a dynamic "collection". Of course you need to somehow tell Blender what geometry belongs to which element: one way would be to connect "Mesh Island: Island Index" to the "group ID".

(Using Blender 4.2.1)
The instance Index can be captured before the Realize Instances node, then used as Group ID input in the Split to Instances node to recover each original instance.

(NB: the Switch node and the Rotate Instances node are for demonstration purpose only, to show that the instances order is not modified)
Resources:
(Blender 4.2.1+)

just wondering for this case, when there is boolean operation applied after the realization, I am using sample nearest surface or nearest index to get the captured instance ID for the booleaned edges, is there some more elegant/better way?
